# how to plot in highcharts from json with two values in x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to plot in highcharts from json with two values in x axis?

```
series: [  
           {  
              type:'pie',
              name:'SVL Cmode',
              data:arr
           }
        ]
```

Comment: Do you want to ask: "How to create multiple series?" or "How to create multiple points?" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

We can create two array from json format. please make sure you should have values for each name .

---

{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Sum of calcAllocated GB',
             data : arr1
        }, 
         {   type: 'column',
            name: 'Sum of calcPurchRAWPrimaryGB',
             data: arr2
        } ]